# Modal don't show after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, sweetalert2

I have a modal which is called by SweetAlert2 library, the problem is that it works fine on the first call, but after reloading the page, it is no longer called. The variable ageVerification only works on the first call, then it is cleared and I need to show the modal window until the user confirms it.

```
const blurContent = $('#global_wrap')
let ageVerification = '{{$ageVerification}}'
function showModal(){
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Confirm you age',
    text: 'You must be at least 18 years old to enter',
    icon: 'question',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'I am over 18',
    cancelButtonText: 'I am under 18',
    confirmButtonColor: '#ee5934',
    allowEscapeKey: false,
    allowEnterKey: false,
    didRender: () => {
      localStorage.setItem(ageVerification, 'false')
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    if(result.isConfirmed){
      blurContent.removeAttr('style')
      localStorage.removeItem(ageVerification)
    }
    if(result.dismiss){
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Declined',
        text: 'Unfortunately, you cannot use this site',
        icon: 'error',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
      })
    }
  })
}
if(ageVerification || localStorage.getItem(ageVerification) === 'false') {
    showModal()
  blurContent.css('filter', 'blur(20px)')
}
```

The if else condition doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I don't know if it can help but `result.dismiss` should be `result.isDismissed` or/and `result.isDenied`

Comment: No, its works fine. The i think that problem in 'if' condition